# Функция принимающая делегат и добавляющая его в Mouse события PictureBox

Tags: c#, делегаты, winforms, события

Решил создать собственный класс, который заполнял бы форму динамически созданными PictureBox. После создания самого PictureBox к нему надо привязать события мыши. Никак не могу додуматься и найти информацию, как это можно сделать.

На данный момент упрощенно имею:

```
public class PictureBoxComponent
{
    private PictureBox pictureBox;

    public PictureBoxComponent(Panel panel)
    {
        this.pictureBox = new PictureBox();

        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox)).BeginInit();

        panel.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox);

        this.pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox.Name = "pictureBoxComponent";
        this.pictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        this.pictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        this.pictureBox.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox.TabStop = false;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox)).EndInit();
    }

    public delegate void MouseEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
    public PictureBoxComponent onMouseClick(MouseEvent f)
    {
        this.pictureBox.Click += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(f);
        return this;
    }
}
```

При присвоении this.pictureBox.Click += получаю ошибку:

> cannot implicitly convert type System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler to System.EventHandler

Как это правильно реализовать? И еще, возможно ли регистрировать анонимные функции в событиях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему бы не воспользоваться существующем делегат-типом?

```
public PictureBoxComponent AddMouseClick(MouseEventHandler f)
{
    this.pictureBox.MouseClick += f;
    return this;
}
```

Возможно, лучшим решением было бы выставить event наружу и пробросить его на `pictureBox`:

```
public event MouseEventHandler PictureboxClick
{
    add { this.pictureBox.MouseClick += value; } 
    remove { this.pictureBox.MouseClick -= value; }
}
```

Если вам нужно использовать именно `Click`, а не `MouseClick` (разницу смотрите [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx)), поменяйте `MouseClick` на `Click`, а `MouseEventHandler` — на `EventHandler`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, встроенный делегат помог. Единственное поправлю, оказывается на Click надо вешать не MouseEventHandler, а просто System.EventHandlet.

Comment: @Alexey123: угу, я уже заметил и обновил ответ. Для `MouseClick` — `MouseEventHandler`, для `Click` — `EventHandler`.